# pymongo : bson.errors.InvalidBSON: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I have a script which copies data from one collection to other.
But sometimes scripts stops with following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "request_archive.py", line 80, in <module>
    ret = archive_requests(dbType)
  File "request_archive.py", line 41, in archive_requests
    for doc in reportCursor : 
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1176, in next
    if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1087, in _refresh
    self.__send_message(q)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 970, in __send_message
    codec_options=self.__codec_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1057, in _unpack_response
    return response.unpack_response(cursor_id, codec_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/message.py", line 945, in unpack_response
    return bson.decode_all(self.documents, codec_options)
bson.errors.InvalidBSON: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 2: invalid start byte
```

When I try to find, which document caused this issue, it is generally like this, in mongo :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("38636f733444373635323637"),
    "mobiles" : "..��..��..��..��..��..��..��..��..��..��etc/passwd",
    "requestDate" : ISODate("2018-03-19T09:32:45.000Z"),
    "isCopied" : NumberLong(0)
}
```

How to handle this?

I am not able to put it into try-catch also, as the error is caused on line, while iterating over cursor.
I found some answers on SO but that ain't working.

I am using python-2.7 and pymongo v3.6.0.

**Edit 1:**

This is how, I am copying data :

```
findData = {'isCopied' : 0 , 'requestDate' : { '$lte' : today } }
collection1Cursor = collection1.find(findData)
for doc in collection1Cursor : # getting error in this line
    updateArr.append(doc['_id'])
    doc.pop('isCopied', None)
    dataArr.append(doc)

collection2.insert(dataArr,continue_on_error=True)
collection1.update_many({'_id' : {'$in' : updateArr}},{'$set' : {'isCopied' : 1}})
```

Comment: How are you copying from one collection to the other? I can advise here to copy documents singly in a try-except block and log the offending documents. Also, it's clear from the logs that you're using python27 and not 3. You may want to run the current code on python3 and see if it solves the error with encoding.✌️

Comment: @OluwafemiSule : I have added the code, for copying. And about copying singly, it is not possible as I have around 10 million new documents for each day. And it will be lots of query calls. I will try to check with python3 and will update the same.

Comment: were you able to resolve this?

Comment: @JaysonKaeze Not that time, but I think this can help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314776/pymongo-error-bson-errors-invalidbson-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xa1-in-p/45881991

Answer (score 0):

Please use this in MongoClient either as connection string or other format as below

It worked for me.

```
?unicode_decode_error_handler=ignore

host='',unicode_decode_error_handler='ignore'
```